# D3: Resizing x axis and repositioning circles

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've inherited a D3 chart that displays events across a timeline, the events are displayed as circles.
To establish the x axis the page uses the following where *show_date* is a column in a csv file.

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.show_date; }));
```

I need to be able to change the timeline to display events from today and the next 4 weeks, next 3, 6 and 12 months. I have a button to call a function

```
<input class="btn" id="weeks4" type="button" value="Next 4 weeks" onclick="timelineView(28);"/>
```

and the function that I created is

```
// n is the number of days to forward view
function timelineView(n) {

var days = n*24*60*60*1000;

x.domain([new Date(), new Date().getTime()+(days)]);
g.selectAll("g.x-axis")
    .transition()
    .duration(1750)
    .call(d3.axisTop(x));

svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(MyData)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)     
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.show_date; });
}
```

It successfully changes the x axis to view the correct amount of time but all of the circles move to the very left of the chart. When I inspect a circle I can see the cx value is a date instead of a number. 
Elsewhere in the code I found this which is what's used when the chart first loads

```
.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.data.x; })
```

so I've tried using that too but the circles stay where they are. How do I make the circles move inline with the updated x axis? I've also been playing with .exit() as there will be less circles to display than when the chart first loads but haven't got anywhere with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

you should check your scale type `scaleBand`, `scaleLinear`, `scaleTime` etc, it must be `scaleTime`,
change the domain to

```
x.domain([new Date()*1, new Date().getTime()+(days)]);
```

try `console.log` this

```
.attr("cx", function(d) { console.log(d.show_date); return d.show_date; });
```

if it return date as a date not as number change to

```
.attr("cx", function(d) { console.log(d.show_date); return new Date(d.show_date)*1 });
```

if not working, try post some working code, so some one can understand better

if you scale is `var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);`

try

```
.attr("cx", function(d) { console.log(d.show_date); return x(d.show_date) });
```

Comment: I changed the code to your first two suggestions and the cx value for one of the circles was 'Tue Jan 1 2019 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)' (each circle displayed similar). I then applied your third suggestion and the cx value was 1546261200000 and all of the circles disappeared. I wanted to provide working code but wasn't sure exactly what to post without posting all 500+ lines.

Comment: are you change the domain sir? what scale do you use?

Comment: var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);

Comment: try .attr("cx", function(d) { console.log(d.show_date); return x(d.show_date); });

Comment: Wow, that did it, thanks. I just need to work out how to apply .exit() to remove the events that fall outside of the x axis.

Comment: you can.. but just miss little thing like this, try focus dring water, sorry for broken english